# EOS blockchain fetching data | How to fetch transactions from eos blockchain?

Tags: discord, blockchain, eos

I have a problem to write my discord bot. So i wondering how i can get transactions from EOS blockchain and specific username and then filter the transactions by actions indetificator and then export data to discord bot to send a message with this. Thanks.

I only got token for the auth of specific username. Tried search for free providers but i didnt get anything good.